# Should i be using StringIndexer on int column?

Tags: pyspark

Hello so i have a pyspark dataframe with the columns "month" and "day_of_week".

these are represented by numeric values already with :

- 1 representing januaray in "month" a
- 1 in "day_of_week" representing Monday.

These are when i printSchem(), identified as integer.

Should i be passing through StringIndexer to identify them as categorical variable for machine learning or can i just leave it as is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringIndexer` is designed to handle [**categorical** columns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#stringindexer) (String type). So the answer is no, you can leave it as is.

Comment: just wondering if then would i just be able to directly apply one hot encoding to the above columns (without indexing)

Comment: Hm, [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) usually come together with categorical features, so it's kind of weird when using it in your use case. I never try it myself, but I suppose it would work.